# Real functions implementation in C++ and operator+ overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, abstract-class

I would like to implement real functions in C++. In particular I would like to evaluate, differentiate, add, multiply such objects. Here is my implementation

```cpp
class RealFunc {
public:
    virtual int Eval(const double& x, double& result) = 0;
    virtual int Diff(const double& x, double& result) = 0;
};

class Sqrt : public RealFunc {
public:
    int Eval(const double& x, double& result);
    int Diff(const double& x, double& result); 
};

int Sqrt::Eval(const double& x, double& result) {
    if(x<0) return 0;
    else {
        result = sqrt(x);
        return 1;
    }
};

int Sqrt::Diff(const double& x, double& result) {
    if(x<=0) return 0;
    else {
        result = 0.5/sqrt(x);
        return 1;
    }
};
```

It gets tricky when I try to add `RealFunc` objects. I have to create a sum class that inherits from `RealFunc`

```cpp
RealFunc operator+(const RealFunc& f, const RealFunc& g) {
    Sum_RealFunc h(f,g);
    return h;
};

class Sum_RealFunc : public RealFunc {
public:
    Sum_RealFunc(const RealFunc& f_, const RealFunc& g_) : f(f_), g(g_) {};
    int Eval(const double& x, double& result);
    int Diff(const double& x, double& result);
private:
    RealFunc f;
    RealFunc g;
};

int Sum_RealFunc::Eval(const double& x, double& result) {
    double temp_f,temp_g;
    int success_f,success_g;
    success_f = f.Eval(x,temp_f);
    success_g = g.Eval(x,temp_g);
    result = temp_f+temp_g;
    return success_f*success_g;
};

// Same for Sum_RealFunc::Diff
```

My issue here is that I cannot use `f`,`g` as members in `Sum_RealFunc` since `RealFunc` is abstract... How should I proceed to get a clean implementation ?

PS : The code I put is a light version of what I am working on (functions from RxR->R with all differentiation directions, finite difference if stepsize member is not zero and other side functions)

Comment: Your question is symptomatic of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you think that you need a `RealFunc` abstract base class ? *Why* does this base class *has* `double` attributes ? It looks to me like a very confused design, and the solutions proposed so far are only going to complicate it.

Comment: You are right my problem is my design. The answers I got so far are quite complicated but my initial problem is quite simple. I would like to add functions basically, a function being an object containing its evaluation f(x) and its exact derivatives (although one could trigger an option to differentiate using finite differences).

Comment: How would you evaluate higher order derivatives when diff returns a number?

Comment: @MatthieuM. I think the problem is that in my implementation, the function sqrt is not an object of class `RealFunc` but another subclass.

Comment: @user877329 in this example `Diff` stands for "first derivative". In my real implementation I use functions of two variables and I am only interested in derivatives up to the second order so I got `DiffX`, `DiffY`, `DiffXX` for instance.

Comment: @MatthieuM. what completely different approach would you propose? The only alternative I could think of it to templatize everything recursively; that might work but you'd need to have everything predetermined at compile time, the code bloat might mitigate the theoretically better performance, and I doubt it would be less "confused".

Comment: @leftaroundabout: it seems I did not understood the original problem (which is why I did not actually answered). I thought the OP wanted to do computations on `double` while apparently he wants to implement an abstract representation of mathematical formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
class Sum_RealFunc : public RealFunc {
    public:
        Sum_RealFunc(RealFunc& f_, RealFunc& g_) : f(f_), g(g_) {};
        int Eval(const double& x, double& result);
        int Diff(const double& x, double& result);
    private:
        RealFunc& f;
        RealFunc& g;
};
```

Now f and g are refernces instead which is fine.

Comment: That's not safe: const references _do_ prolong the lifetime of the variable to the frame of a directly-called function, but after that the the constructor is finished they will still leave scope, so `Sum_RealFunc s(somefreefunc(foo), g); s.Eval(bar, baz)` will not work.

Comment: Ok but when I implement `Sum_RealFunc::Eval` calls like `f.Eval(x,result)` returns the following error : `cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const RealFunc' to 'RealFunc &'`

Comment: @vanna This is because you asserted that the sum does not change the state of a function. You now need to say: int Eval(const double& x,double& result) const;

and the same for diff

Comment: @leftaroundabout That is true. But just remove all const:s and we have forced somefreefunc to survive. Declaring Eval and Diff as const member functions is probably good anyway.

Comment: I declared my functions const and it worked. This is what I needed, thanks a lot.

Comment: @vanna But be aware of leftaroundabouts comment

Comment: @user877329 I will. I am new to these notions so I should go with the naive approach first to understand the need for more complex C++ tools.

Comment: I am tempted to give -1 (but am not doing it for now) because keeping unmanaged references to f and g (which will probably be allocated on the stack) is a dangerous thing that a beginner should simply *not* do.

Comment: Also note that the operator+ as shown in the question will not work, as it "slices" the object (google for that).

Comment: @wolfgang (a) Suppose that we actuall don't us const references but references. Then there is no problem at all since all bad stuff is completely forbidden. The referenced object will always survive because it was created first.

Comment: @wolfgang (b) Yes the operator+ has to return a Sum_RealFunc. The code given for the operator wont compile because it tries to copy an instance of a purely abstract class.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are facing is that you need both a feature that works well with value objects (operator overloading) and features that only works with pointers (inheritance/polymorphism).

As a solution, you'd need to have a value object with overloaded operators as a wrapper for polymorphic objects managed via pointers:

```
class RealFuncImpl {
public:
    virtual ~RealFuncImpl(); // don't forget this for polymorphic objects

    virtual int Eval(const double& x, double& result) = 0;
    virtual int Diff(const double& x, double& result) = 0;
};

class RealFunc {
    std::shared_ptr<RealFuncImpl> impl;
public:

    int Eval(const double& x, double& result);
    int Diff(const double& x, double& result);
};
```

You'd derive your `Sum_RealFuncImpl` from `RealFuncImpl` and implement your operators for `RealFunc`. You should probably hide away your `Impl` classes in some "detail" namespace, as your code's end user should never see them.

EDIT:

Your `Sum_RealFuncImpl` would contain two `std::shared_ptr<RealFuncImpl>` members.

Comment: I recommend **NOT** using `shared_ptr`, but rather using `unique_ptr` (in C++11) or `scoped_ptr` or simply redevelopping a Pimpl class (it's not so hard). You do *not* want shared ownership here.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: you need a way to clone the function objects to use `unique_ptr` practically. I you want to avoid that, `shared_ptr` is quite a reasonable compromise, though I agree it's not optimal.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: the problem is that in the OP design, the so called functions carry state, so *sharing is not so reasonable*.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: What state are you talking about? I don't see any state. The OP seems to expect to be able to treat the functions as (immutable) values, and to be allowed to copy them around. Hence, I stand by `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @wolfgang: The `Eval` and `Diff` functions not being `const` (and `Sum_RealFunc` having two attributes), I assumed the OP wanted to have stateful functions. With hindsight, it seems the OP is simply not too C++ savvy.

Comment: @vanna: Yep, unfortunately this is trivial for me so I tend to assume it is for others too... my own fault really :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you initialize them in the constructors initializer list, you can make the member variables references.

Comment: What do you mean ? If I change `RealFunc f` to `RealFunc& f` for instance the compiler tells me `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const RealFunc' to 'RealFunc &'`

Comment: @vanna: that is because you are missing a `const` qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

- Do as wolfgang suggested: use only a wrapper around a shared pointer. This way you can create copies without really having to copy the derived function objects.
- Make the derived classes themselves copyable through a base-class pointer, by implementing a `clone` member. That's most conveniently done with deriving from a CRTP class instead of directly from the base class. I'd make it a local class, to not confuse things:

  ```
  struct RealFunc {
    virtual std::pair<double,bool> operator()       //IMO better than this
                            (double x)const =0;    // reference-argument hackery
    virtual std::pair<double,bool> Diff
                               (double x)const =0;

    virtual RealFunc* clone()const =0;
    template<class Derived>
    struct implementation : RealFunc {
      RealFunc* clone() {
        return new Derived(*static_cast<const Derived*>(this));
      }
    };

    virtual ~RealFunc(){}
  };
  ```

  Now you just have to derive your function objects from `implementation`, to make them clonable:

  ```
  struct Sqrt : RealFunc::implementation<Sqrt> {
    std::pair<double,bool> operator()(double x) {
      return x>=0
              ? std::make_pair(sqrt(x), true)
              : std::make_pair(0., false);
    }
    ...
  }
  ```

  Your sum function can now be done nicely with `std::unique_ptr`:

  ```
  class Sum_RealFunc : public RealFunc::implementation<Sum_RealFunc> {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<RealFunc>> summands;
   public:
    std::pair<double,bool> operator()(double x) {
      double result=0;
      for(auto& f: summands) {
        auto r = (*f)(x);
        if(r.second) result += r.first;
         else return std::make_pair(0., false);
      }
      return std::make_pair(result, true);
    }

    Sum_RealFunc(const Sum_RealFunc& cpy) {
      for(auto& f: cpy.summands)
        summands.push_back(f->clone());
    }

    //friend operator+=(RealFunc& acc, const RealFunc& add); //doesn't work
  };
  ```

  Unfortunately, this is *not* enough indirection to allow writing simple sum expressions. I did something in a recent project that solved pretty much all of these issues, but was yet a bit more complicated: I gave *every* instance the option to override its behaviour with any other instance. Like

  ```
  class RealFunc {
    std::unique_ptr<RealFunc> override;
   public:
    virtual std::pair<double,bool> operator()(double x)const {
      return (*override)(x);
    }
    virtual std::pair<double,bool> Diff(double x)const {
      return override->Diff(x);
    }

    auto implemented() -> RealFunc*                              {
      return implement_override? override->implemented() : this; }
    auto implemented()const -> const RealFunc*                   {
      return implement_override? override->implemented() : this; }

    virtual RealFunc* clone()const =0;
    template<class Derived>
    struct implementation : RealFunc {
      virtual std::pair<double,bool> operator()(double x)const =0;
      virtual std::pair<double,bool> Diff(double x)const =0;
      RealFunc* clone() {
        return new Derived(*static_cast<const Derived*>(this));
      }
    };

    virtual ~RealFunc(){}
  };
  ```

  That's not all, you need to include a lot of checks for `override` everywhere with this approach. But in the end, it allows you to combine functions very smoothly, like

  ```
  RealFunc f = const_realfunc(7.);
  for(auto& omega: omegas)
    f += sine_angfreq(omega);
  RealFunc g = f + noise_func(.3);
  ...
  ```

Comment: Good point about returning `std::pair<double,bool>` instead of messing around with references.

Comment: What does all that complexity buy us? Rather than writing `RealFunc myFun = f + g;` we'd have to write something like... `std::unique_ptr<Sum_RealFunc> myFun(new Sum_RealFunc); (*myFun) += *f; (*myFun) += *g;`

Comment: @wolfgang: actually, there is a `NaN` state in `double` so the boolean is unnecessary.

Comment: @MatthieuM. sure there is `NaN`, but that is very cumbersome: one easily forgets to check for it, and then you're stuck with those ugly hard-to-trace values failing to fulfill `x==x`. I'd only go that way if I had to optimise for memory and performance. — Returning always non-`NaN` doubles, but raising an exception in the case of failure might be a viable alternative.